# Android code working slower than intended

Tags: java, android, performance, optimization, arduino

Sorry for my bad english,
I'm doing a project for school where i have to move a vehicle via WiFi with an Android App. I achieved my goal but I got surprised to see that, most of the times when I pressed any button, my vehicle took some time to actually do something. On the other hand, when I press any button a few times quickly, the events stack, and after, even when I'm not pressing any button, the vehicle moves. Needless to say, both are several problems. Is there any way to fix them?.
The Android App conects via REST API to an Arduino Yun. With each touch on a button i'm making an HTTP Request in order to move the vehicle Forward, Backwards, Left or Right.
 Here's my code (Despite the spanish, I think it's understandable):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Button  boton1,
                boton2,
                boton3,
                boton4;
private String  valor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    configuracion();
}
public void configuracion(){
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.
            ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    establecerBotones();
    try{
    definir("continua/0/0");
    definir("direccion/0/0");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Alerta();
    }
}

public void establecerBotones(){ 
    boton1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.boton1);      //all buttons do something similar
    boton1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch(action){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    v.setPressed(true);
                    conectar("continua/1/0");
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    v.setPressed(false);
                    try {
                        conectar("continua/0/0");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    boton2= (Button)findViewById(R.id.boton2); 
    boton2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    });
    boton3= (Button)findViewById(R.id.boton3); 
    boton3.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    });
    boton4= (Button)findViewById(R.id.boton4); 
    boton4.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    });
}

private void conectar(final String selector) {
      new Thread() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
                 try {
                     // code runs in a thread
                       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                              @Override
                              public void run() {
                                  try {
                                    definir (selector);
                                  } catch (Exception e) {
                                    System.out.println("holi");
                                  }
                              }
                       });
                 } catch (final Exception ex) {
                }
          }
   }.start();
}
public void definir(String selector) throws Exception{
    valor = "http://192.168.240.1/arduino/" + selector;
    URL url = new URL(valor);
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    try {
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        leer(in);
        }
    finally {
         urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
}

public void leer(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    if ((reader.readLine()) != "1") throw new IOException(); 
    //Arduino is programmed to print "1" when connection succedes
}

public void Alerta(){                           
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Conexion erronea";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
}
```

PD: I'm kind of a beginner at programming, and I started learning java (and android) purely on my own this year. I'm probably doing some "dumb" errors on my code. I would appreciate any help or advice. Thank you for reading.

Comment: It looks like you are downloading your data on the UI thraed. Take a look at `AsyncTask`

Comment: I did, but i still don't understand how I could apply it and why it would be a benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the code, as mentioned in comments. Android behaves badly if you do things that take any time on the UI thread. You need to move external connections onto a separate thread and find a way to communicate through it. As a newbie programmer you are going to find this hard, but there are lots of code samples around to help.

But this (and the code you posted) has nothing to do with your real problem. You have an "open loop" control mechanism and you need to close the loop. You need a way for the controlled device to respond with some information about whether it has moved or is moving, and you need to modify your control strategy accordingly.

Alternatively, you can send more complex commands to the vehicle (like "left 3" or "straight ahead") and leave the loop monitoring to the vehicle's on-board processor.

These are all common problems and you will find plenty of general reading material with very little searching. When you have very specific questions, Stack Overflow may be able to help better.